# Wiremock - global response templating causing 500 when returning certain media files

Tags: wiremock

I have a test project that requires global response templating to be enabled, because lots of the mocked responses contain dynamic content.

The problem is, I also need to return images/videos for some responses, and this does not appear to play nicely with the response templating for some for the images/videos (but not all).

It appears as though when it tries to return the video response, it tries to apply templating to the image file, and complains that there are invalid chars within the response, at least thats what I think this stack is telling me (this isn't shown in the wiremock server logs, its wrapped into an HTML body and returned as the response).

```
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>500</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>wiremock.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: inline@1756a128:1:2: found: &apos;?&apos;
{{?-)2?}?/&gt;4?????{?E??????????????????%???z??x???S????2z???{?;??fs??Wn??e?wGwr?????(t+?[??????n??ww}?{&lt;)?U??t??
  ^
</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet-6e20b53a</td></tr>
<tr><th>CAUSED BY:</th><td>wiremock.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: inline@1756a128:1:2: found: &apos;?&apos;
{{?-)2?}?/&gt;4?????{?E??????????????????%???z??x???S????2z???{?;??fs??Wn??e?wGwr?????(t+?[??????n??ww}?{&lt;)?U??t??
  ^
</td></tr>
<tr><th>CAUSED BY:</th><td>wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: inline@1756a128:1:2: found: &apos;?&apos;
{{?-)2?}?/&gt;4?????{?E??????????????????%???z??x???S????2z???{?;??fs??Wn??e?wGwr?????(t+?[??????n??ww}?{&lt;)?U??t??
  ^
</td></tr>
</table>
<h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>wiremock.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: inline@1756a128:1:2: found: &apos;?&apos;
{{?-)2?}?/&gt;4?????{?E??????????????????%???z??x???S????2z???{?;??fs??Wn??e?wGwr?????(t+?[??????n??ww}?{&lt;)?U??t??
  ^

    at wiremock.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2051)
    at wiremock.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3962)
    at wiremock.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4859)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.ResponseTemplateTransformer.getTemplate(ResponseTemplateTransformer.java:242)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.ResponseTemplateTransformer.transform(ResponseTemplateTransformer.java:158)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.stubbing.InMemoryStubMappings.applyTransformations(InMemoryStubMappings.java:101)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.stubbing.InMemoryStubMappings.serveFor(InMemoryStubMappings.java:80)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockApp.serveStubFor(WireMockApp.java:209)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.StubRequestHandler.handleRequest(StubRequestHandler.java:56)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.AbstractRequestHandler.handle(AbstractRequestHandler.java:64)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet.service(WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet.java:121)
    at wiremock.javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:735)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: inline@1756a128:1:2: found: &apos;?&apos;
{{?-)2?}?/&gt;4?????{?E??????????????????%???z??x???S????2z???{?;??fs??Wn??e?wGwr?????(t+?[??????n??ww}?{&lt;)?U??t??
  ^

    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.HbsErrorReporter.syntaxError(HbsErrorReporter.java:93)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.antlr.ProxyErrorListener.syntaxError(ProxyErrorListener.java:41)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.HbsParserFactory$2.notifyListeners(HbsParserFactory.java:136)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.antlr.Lexer.nextToken(Lexer.java:144)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.antlr.BufferedTokenStream.fetch(BufferedTokenStream.java:169)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.antlr.BufferedTokenStream.sync(BufferedTokenStream.java:152)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.antlr.BufferedTokenStream.consume(BufferedTokenStream.java:136)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.antlr.atn.ParserATNSimulator.execATN(ParserATNSimulator.java:537)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.antlr.atn.ParserATNSimulator.adaptivePredict(ParserATNSimulator.java:393)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.HbsParser.body(HbsParser.java:215)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.HbsParser.template(HbsParser.java:164)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.HbsParserFactory$1.parse(HbsParserFactory.java:86)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.cache.NullTemplateCache.get(NullTemplateCache.java:54)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.Handlebars.compile(Handlebars.java:513)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.Handlebars.compileInline(Handlebars.java:473)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.Handlebars.compileInline(Handlebars.java:453)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.HandlebarsOptimizedTemplate.uncheckedCompileTemplate(HandlebarsOptimizedTemplate.java:54)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wirem
100  9076  100  9076    0     0  55629      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 55680
ock.extension.responsetemplating.HandlebarsOptimizedTemplate.&lt;init&gt;(HandlebarsOptimizedTemplate.java:49)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.ResponseTemplateTransformer$3.call(ResponseTemplateTransformer.java:245)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.ResponseTemplateTransformer$3.call(ResponseTemplateTransformer.java:242)
    at wiremock.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4864)
    at wiremock.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529)
    at wiremock.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at wiremock.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155)
    at wiremock.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
    ... 40 more
</pre>
```

Here is the code I am using to upload the file:

```
byte[] attachmentVideo = FileUtils.loadFileBytes("classpath:payloads/video.mp4");
        response = given().body(attachmentVideo).contentType("video/mp4").put(wiremockUrl() + FILES_ENDPOINT + "video.mp4");
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), is(HttpStatus.SC_OK));
```

Here is the code to return the file:

```
        wiremock.register(WireMock.get(WireMock.urlMatching(ATTACHMENT_VIDEO_REGEX))
                .willReturn(aResponse().withBodyFile("video.mp4").withHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4")
                        .withStatus(200).withFixedDelay(VIDEO_RESPONSE_TIME_MS)));
```

As soon as I turn off global response templating, the video is returning as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option here is to switch to local response templating at startup via `.global(false)` in the builde and add `.withTransformers("response-template")` to the stubs that require it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a transformer parameter to disable the templating of the media file :

```
"disableBodyFileTemplating": true
```

Credits to Tom